# how to reboot a Linux system when a fatal error occurs (C programming)

Tags: c, linux, error-handling, debian, reboot

I am writing a C program for an embedded Linux (debian-arm) device. In some cases, e.g. if a fatal error occurs on the system/program, I want the program to reboot the system by `system("reboot");`after logging the error(s) via `syslog()`. My program includes `multithreads`, `UDP sockets`, several`fwrite()/fopen()`, `malloc()` calls, ..

I would like to ask a few question what (how) the program should perform processes just before rebooting the system apart from the `syslog`. I would appreciate to know how these things are done by the experienced programmers.

- Is it necessary to close the open sockets (UDP) and threads just before rebooting? If it is the case, is there a function/system call that closes the all open sockets and threads? If the threads needs to be closed and there is no such global function/call to end them, how I suppose to execute `pthread_exit(NULL);` for  each specific threads? Do I need go use something like `goto` to end the each threads?
- How should the program closes files that `fopen` and `fwrite` uses? Is there a global call to   close the files in use or do I need to find out the files in use manually then use `fclose` for the each file? I see see some examples on the forums `fflush()`, `flush()`, `sync()`,..  are used, which one(s) would you recommend to use? In a generic case, would it cause any problem if all of these functions are used (although these could be used unnecessary)?
- It is not necessary to `free` the variables that `malloc` allocated space, is it?

Do you suggest any other tasks to be performed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system automatically issues `SIGTERM` signals to all processes as one of the steps in rebooting.  As long as you correctly handle `SIGTERM`, you need not do anything special after invoking the `reboot` command.  The normal idiom for "correctly handling `SIGTERM`" is:

- Create a pipe to yourself.
- The signal handler for `SIGTERM` writes one byte (any value will do) to that pipe.
- Your main `select` loop includes the read end of that pipe in the set of file descriptors of interest.  If that pipe ever becomes readable, it's time to exit.

Furthermore, when a process exits, the kernel automatically closes all  its open file descriptors, terminates all of its threads, and deallocates all of its memory. And if you exit *cleanly*, i.e. by returning from `main` or calling `exit`, all stdio `FILE`s that are still open are automatically flushed and closed.  Therefore, you probably don't have to do very much cleanup on the way out -- the most important thing is to make sure you finish generating any output files and remove any temporary files.

You may find the concept of [crash-only software](http://static.usenix.org/events/hotos03/tech/candea.html) useful in figuring out what does and does not need cleaning up.

Comment: thank you for the both answers, I have one little question. how can I execute `exit(1)` just before the `system("reboot")`? Would it be executed if I call the `exit()` after `system("reboot")` since it would take some seconds for system to be reboot?

Comment: I would just go ahead and call `exit` after `system("reboot")`.  If you're really worried about it, use a mini-shell script to delay the `reboot` operation: `system("(sleep 1 && reboot) &")`  But this will slow the rebooting process down, so I would suggest you not bother unless it appears to be a problem in testing.

Answer (score 2):

The only cleanup you need to do is anything your program needs to start up in a consistent state. For example, if you collect some data internally then write it to a file, you will need to ensure this is done before exiting. Other than that, you do not need to close sockets, close files, or free all memory. The operating system is designed to release these resources on process exit.